# MySQL 5.5 'Binary log is not open', Error_code: 1236

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I am trying to configure master-master replication however I am getting an error. I am sending my configuration below

Server A

```
server-id = 1
replicate-same-server-id = 0
auto-increment-increment = 2
auto-increment-offset = 1

master-host = Kooler-PC
master-user = replicacao
master-password = replicacao
master-connect-retry = 60
replicate-do-db = gestao_quadra

log-bin = C:\mysql\log\log-bin.log
binlog-do-db = gestao_quadra
```

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='Kooler-PC', MASTER_USER='replicacao', MASTER_PASSWORD='replicacao', MASTER_LOG_FILE='log-bin.log ', MASTER_LOG_POS=0;

I am have done the same steps for other server changing server-id, host and created the file in the path.

I get this error:

```
130218 18:03:02 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'replicacao@Kooler-PC:3306',replication started in log 'log-bin.log ' at position 4
130218 18:03:02 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Binary log is not open ( server_errno=1236)
130218 18:03:02 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open', Error_code: 1236
130218 18:03:02 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'log-bin.log ', position 4
```

I am using MySQL 5.5

Comment: Is the binlog enabled on the master? Can you post the master's configuration as well?

Comment: Yes, It is the same config as above except host and server-id

Answer (score 2):

So if you read the mysql manual on replication an binary logging, it would tell you that this line:

```
log-bin = C:\mysql\log\log-bin.log
```

Does not create a log file with exactly that name.  It specifies the base name.  The log files that actually get created would be named:

```
C:\mysql\log\log-bin.log.000001
```

That is to say the actual logs have a sequence number appended to the end of the name you specified.  To see the actual log names use the command:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

This part of your change master statement is not valid:

```
MASTER_LOG_FILE='log-bin.log ', MASTER_LOG_POS=0;
```

There's no part of any replication related instructions I've ever read which would lead you to use position 0.  You have to use the master's binary log file and position that correspond to the snapshot of the data with which you initialized the slave.

See the manual for more info.  Start with basic master->slave replication first before you attempt more complex replication structures.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html